# Existential Types. Writing the instance of a class for an heterogeneous map

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Using the following type and class definitions, I do not understand why I get and error when creating the `instance` below.

I need MyMap to hold a map of heterogeneous values.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
module Scratch.SO_ExtistentialTypes where

import Data.Map

type MyMap a = Map String a

class MyClass c where 
    getMyMap :: forall a. c -> MyMap a

data MyData = forall a. MyData {
    myMap ::  MyMap a
}

instance MyClass MyData where
    getMyMap = myMap -- <= ERROR
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Because I seriously doubt this is a good way to go about it.

Comment: @C.A.McCann The `type` and `class` are part of a module that defines an 'API'. The `data`and `type`are the (simplified) tentative implementations.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Another way to put it is: how can create a data type (MyData) that can be made an instance of MyClass ?

Comment: As it stands, the only reasonable definition of `getMyMap` is one that ignores its input and returns an empty `Map` every time. I assume that's not what you want, so you might want to rethink the purpose of `MyClass`.

Comment: There is a more restricted notion of heterogeneous map that makes sense in a typed setting, where the type of the value depends on an index of the key. You might have `data Map (k :: * -> *) = ...`, and then you'd have a function like `lookup :: Ord1 k => Map k -> k a -> a`. Now if you instantiate the parameter to `Map` to a GADT that refines its indices, you can have different keys map to different value types. I wrote one of these a while ago but can't find it right now. Perhaps it'll help you clear up what you want, though.

Comment: @copumkin I made this a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097890/an-heterogeneous-map-without-existential-types)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For one thing, the `forall` here is superfluous:

```
class MyClass c where 
    getMyMap :: forall a. c -> MyMap a
```

Type variables with no explicit binding are universally quantified at the outermost level, so this is exactly the same as just `c -> MyMap a`.

Beyond that, a universally quantified type is certainly not going to match an existentially quantified type. The type of `getMyMap` says that, given a value of type `c`, it will produce a value of type `MyMap a` for any possible choice of type `a`. On the other hand, the accessor `myMap` says that, given a value of type `MyData`, it will produce a value of type `MyMap a` for some specific but unknown type `a`.

It's not possible to have unwrapped existential types floating around by themselves (this would require an `exists` quantifier corresponding to `forall`), so there's no way to rewrite the type of `getMyMap` such that `myMap` is a valid implementation.

All you can do with something having an existential type is wrap it back up in another data type that hides the existential quantifier, or give it to a function that has an argument with a universally quantified type. For example, you can use `length` on a list `[a]` with `a` an existential type.

In your case, the values of the `Map` have existential type with no other structure or constraints, so they're pretty much useless and might as well be `()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand that `getMyMap` type's definition expresses the wrong thing (it returns a Map of an *universally* quantified type). So, how do I express, in a class, that I need a function that returns a Map of heterogeneous values (if that is at all possible) ?

Comment: @BGR: Expressing such a type is one thing, but the bigger question is actually *using* a structure containing values of heterogeneous types. Arcane techniques for working with such types do exist (ha, ha) but my rule of thumb is "if you need to ask how to do it, don't". If you want a sane API that's not a horrendous pain to use, you probably want a different design.

Comment: :) Fair enough. Thank you for spending the time.

Comment: @BGR: You could probably get some helpful suggestions if you post a new question along the lines of "I want to do X and was told not to use existential types, what should I do instead?". Jumping down the existential rabbit hole is a surprisingly common mistake for beginners, especially those coming from OO languages without rigorous static types.

Comment: right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097890/an-heterogeneous-map-without-existential-types)